# ANDROID: misses variable++ everytime because of pause in debugger

Tags: android, variables, imageview

I have a problem when creating a hangman game.
I'm pretty new to android, only been doing it for a week, but now i'm in a real jam.
I keep loosing an int variable's value at the same place everytime. It is the variable antallGjett (Means number fo guesses). I have pictures in an imageview there and the first is set to zero. First time it is okey, the image changes. But then next time, nothing happens. It never changes to image "hang2" on the second miss, but on the third miss it goes forward. BUT, the counter still have the value 6 at image nr 5. heres the method:

```
public void klikkKnapp(char[] c, Button bokstav, char[] l, char[] gjettetOrd)   {
        boolean bol= sjekkBokstav(c, bokstav, l, gjettetOrd);
        if(bol== false) {
            if(antallGjett>= 6)
                antallGjett= 0;
            ++antallGjett;  //number of guesses
            String pakke= getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            image= getResources().getIdentifier(pakke+":drawable/hang"+ antallGjett+"", null, null); // 
            hangMan= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hengtmann);
            if(hangMan.getId()== image) {
                ++antallGjett;
                image= getResources().getIdentifier(pakke+":drawable/hang"+ antallGjett, null, null);
            }
            hangMan.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), image));
        }
        if(antallGjett== 6) 
            showDialog(false);
        else if(Arrays.equals(ord, gjettetOrd))
            showDialog(true);
    }
```

I have implementet onPause() and onResume() , but it doesent help.
Example of my onPause() method:

```
protected void onPause()    {
      super.onPause();
      Context context = this.getBaseContext();
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY", MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

      editor.putInt("antallGJETT", antallGjett); // value to store
      // Commit to storage
      editor.commit();
    }
```

And here onResume:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()   {
        super.onResume();
        Context context = this.getBaseContext();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref= context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_KEY", MODE_PRIVATE);
        an
```

tallGjett= sharedPref.getInt("antallGJETT", antallGjett);
     }

I have read and read and tried and tried, but i see no solution.. :(

Comment: You're incrementing antallGjett in two separate places.  Is it jumping up in steps of 2?  Skipping 1, 3 and 5?

Comment: This `hangMan.getId()== image` would never be true. You're comparing the id of the View to the id of the bitmap resource.